# How can I proof that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{n^b}{a^n}= 0\;,\;$ when $\;a > 1,\; b > 0\;.$

Tags: limits, analysis, proof-writing

I am having a hard time with this problem:
I tried by using the sandwich theorem but I failed.

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{n^b}{a^n}= 0\;,\;$ when $\;a > 1,\; b > 0\;.$

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: A stronger result is true: $\sum \frac {n^{b}} {a^{n}}$ is convergent: Apply ratio test.

Comment: Could you please show me how to do it. I have no idea.

Comment: This is a well-known fact: Exponential function grows faster, than any polynomial.